# '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0

Tags: c#, jsonserializer

I have a Web two Web API services, once service which  returns byte[]

1st API which returns byte[]

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("compile")]
public async Task<byte[]> GetData([FromBody] Data myDto)
{
    var data = await _myservice.Transform(myDto);
    return data;
}
```

2nd API makes a call to first API gets below error

```
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json,
  ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(
  Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
```

**The above error I get on deployed service, I'm unable to reproduce this error locally [local debug]**

Comment: If you're expecting JSON data but get data beginning with a '<' it is most likely returning an HTML response, probably a 404 html page or something similar.
Print out the returned response and work out why your API is returning HTML (or whatever) instead of JSON.
If it is only happening when deployed then it might be some permissions issue or firewall not being opened, etc. You need to debug what the actual response content is.

Comment: you are right!!!, thanks, i have got it resolved

Answer (score 0):

I got some error like this:
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'M' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

the reason is:

1. I build several project binaries to same folder
2. I am using .net 7
3. after successful build, I running rebuild

the solution now is

1. always delete the same target folder bin, then build solution would be fine,

seems the key reason is that .net 6 do not support building several projects to same binary folder, should build different project to different bin\ folder, then xcopy the build result to same bin folder in Post-build event, if this is needed.

in .vsproj file, should be

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy bin\$(Configuration)\ ..\..\bin\ /s /y /c /q" />
</Target>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Always paste the code as text and format it using the formatting tool.