# How to fix 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' dll issue after take update of Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

After taking update of Visual Studio 2022, I am getting error from Blazor application when I run the application.

Error: `System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'`

[image: Error page]

Please find the error information image and help me to fix the issue.

Updated by adding new image

[image: Updated Image]

Comment: A `<` doesn't really belong into json. Are you trying to decode XML as json? Please show some code and the text that is being parsed.

Comment: Same one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040600/is-an-invalid-start-of-a-value-path-linenumber-0-bytepositioninline

Comment: I think shingo has picked it. You are expecting a JSON payload from an API call, but it is giving you an IIS HTML error page instead. Use Postman or similar to check that your REST API is working properly

Comment: @PMF how can I go to code part where I have to click on the image park. Means... Do I am click on Microsoft Symbol Servers or NuGet.org Symbol Servers. Where from I start actually?

Comment: @Abhishek Just check both and click load, it will attempt to pick the appropriate source.

Comment: @PMF I have updated and added the new poppup window as image 'Updated Image' please check my updated question once.  After check the both one then VS finding 'ThrowHelper.Serialization' file. What to do?

Comment: That second screenshot doesn't help anything. That happens if VS fails to load the sources, which might happen, depending on your setup etc. You should make yourself familiar with the debugger.

Comment: @PMF Now issue is solved. Thanks. I already answered. Please check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by installing `.NET 5.0 Runtime(Out of support)` by selecting Visual Studio Installer => Modify => Individual components => Then Install `.NET 5.0 Runtime(Out of support)`

Comment: IDK but your spidey sense should be tingling when reading (Out of support). Probably means you are using an outdated version of System.Text.Json or some other package.